# npapi plugin: how do I install a gecko plugin?

Tags: linux, gecko, npapi

I've compile the basic plugin found [here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/modules/plugin/sdk/samples/basic/unix/) but I can't figure out how to install it on my Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer: to enable the plugin in Ubuntu's of Firefox, copy your `npbasicplugin.so` to `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/`.

The plugins path for various UNIX browsers has varied a lot.

- `/usr/lib/netscape/plugins/`
- `/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/`
- `/usr/lib/mozilla-firefox/plugins/`
- `/usr/lib/nsbrowser/plugins/`
- `/opt/netscape/plugins/`

Those are only some of the locations that modern browsers on modern distributions seem to use.  Luckily, a distribution usually configures all the browsers they ship to look in a common path, so that you only need to install a plugin to one directory to enable it across all browsers on a system.  (IIRC BSD ports is an exception, but anyhow...)

Comment: thanks .. Under fedora 12 I had to copy it in /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins-wrapped/